Chinese character indentation and number alignment
The code was generated by me in AI, but I repeatedly asked him to fix it, but it didn't achieve a good modification effect
I don't want to control indentation by manually entering \ quad and \ qquad, and I want the values to be aligned to the right, separated from the Chinese characters by a certain distance
How should I modify my code?
The effect in the picture is what I want
The code wrapped in the custom environment must always start with "借：", and at the nth line it must start with "贷：". The lines between "借：" and "贷：" should be indented by the length of "借：", and the lines after "贷：" should be indented by the length of "借：" plus one space.
The content wrapped by the custom environment is flexible, which means there may be an indefinite number of lines between "借：" and "贷：" (or zero). Similarly, the content after "贷：" is also indefinite
If we consider "借：" and "贷：" as the first and second identifiers respectively, then: Lines between these two identifiers should be indented by \qquad The second identifier should be indented by \quad Lines after the second identifier should be indented by \quad \qquad 
Numbers and equations should be placed in the second column and aligned to the right. If there are no numbers or equations, the corresponding second column should be left blank

\documentclass{ctexart}
\usepackage{array}       % Provides enhanced table functionality
\usepackage{environ}     % Provides new environment definition functionality
\usepackage{etoolbox}    % Provides boolean variables and other tools
\usepackage{xstring}     % Provides string processing functionality

% Define boolean variable to track whether current entry is debit or credit
\newbool{isDebit}

% Define command to process each line of text
\newcommand{\processline}[1]{%
    \def\temp{#1}%
    \ifx\temp\empty\else
    \IfBeginWith{\temp}{借：}{%
        \booltrue{isDebit}%
        借：\StrBehind{\temp}{借：}[\content]%
        \processcontent{\content}
    }{%
        \IfBeginWith{\temp}{贷：}{%
            \boolfalse{isDebit}%
            贷：\StrBehind{\temp}{贷：}[\content]%
            \processcontent{\content}
        }{%
            \ifbool{isDebit}
            {\quad }
            {\quad }%
            \processcontent{#1}\\
        }%
    }%
    \fi
}

% Process content, separate text and numbers
\newcommand{\processcontent}[1]{%
    \def\text{}%
    \def\number{}%
    \processcontentaux#1 \@nil
}

% Auxiliary command for processing content
\def\processcontentaux#1 #2\@nil{%
    \def\temp{#2}%
    \ifx\temp\empty
    #1 &
    \else
    \IfInteger{#2}{%
        #1 & #2
    }{%
        \processcontentaux#1 & #2 \@nil
    }%
    \fi
}

% Define accounting entry environment
\NewEnviron{accounting}{%
    \noindent
    \begin{tabular}{>{\hspace{0em}}l@{\hspace{4em}}>{\hfill}p{3em}}
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}%  % Increase line spacing
        \expandafter\processlines\expandafter{\BODY}%
    \end{tabular}
}

% Command to process multiple lines of text
\newcommand{\processlines}[1]{%
    \def\do##1{\ifx##1\empty\else\processline{##1}\fi}%
    \docsvlist{#1}%
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{accounting}
        借：材料采购 50\\
        \qquad 原材料 50\\
        \qquad 应交税金——应交增值税 100*0.13=13\\
        \quad 贷：银行存款 90\\
        \quad \qquad 其他应付款 23\\
    \end{accounting}
\end{document}


Why don't you align the "借" and "贷"？

This is a habit, usually written like this

When I compile your test document with my fully updated MacTeX2024 system, I experience no issue outputting "10*0.13=13". However, the numbers that should be in a column to the far right are now placed simply at the end of each row, with a minimal gap separating them from the other material in the row.

The macro \processcontent takes 1 argument and (eventually) passes this argument to \processcontentaux. The latter macro, however, would appear to expect to receive 2 arguments, not just 1. is \processcontentaux supposed to assume that the second argument is always empty? That would easily explain why the numbers appear to be part of arg 1 when I compile your test document. A separate concern: The macro \processcontent provides dummy definitions of \text and \number; however, the latter 2 macros are never used. Is this an example of an "AI hallucination" artifact?

I can't understand these codes, they are a bit complicated for me. I can roughly understand what you mean, but I can't modify them. If I submit your viewpoint to AI for assistance, the content of AI's answer will still fall into the previous dead loop. It seems that AI cannot give me the correct answer. Could you please provide the complete code? Thank you

Don't ask AI for solutions about LaTeX.

Please explain in words what you're trying to achieve. The reason I ask is that your code is nearly impenetrable (as well as buggy, in all likelihood). As a result, it's really difficult to deduce your intentions from the LaTeX code alone.

Please also explain in more detail what's supposed to happen with the substring "100*0.13=13". Is the entire substring supposed to be placed in the second, right-aligned column? If not, which part should be placed in the second column.

The instructions for the relevant formats have been perfected


\documentclass{ctexart}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\NewTblrEnviron{accounting}
\SetTblrInner[accounting]{colspec={X[l]X[r]},
  cell{2,3}{1}={preto={\qquad}},
  cell{4}{1}={preto={\quad}},
  cell{5}{1}={preto={\quad\qquad}}}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{accounting}{}
  借：材料采购 & 50 \\
  原材料 & 50 \\
  应交税金——应交增值税 & $100\times 0.13=13$ \\
  贷：银行存款 & 90 \\
  其他应付款 & 23 \\
\end{accounting}
\end{document}


I may be wrong, but I think the idea of the string manipulation measures in the OP's (admittedly nearly impenetrable) code was to assess "on the fly" which parts of each input string should be in the first column, by how much (if at all) to indent the material in the first column, and which parts of the input string should be in the second column. Can your code be adapted to do that?

I didn't analyze the code provided by the OP. Maybe he should explain what he wants to achieve more precisely.

I do want the code to automatically handle indentation instead of default, because once I change the content, it's not suitable anymore

@eric How to handle indentation? Can you explain the indentation rule accurately?

The code wrapped in the custom environment must always start with "借：", and at the nth line it must start with "贷：". The lines between "借：" and "贷：" should be indented by the length of "借：", and the lines after "贷：" should be indented by the length of "借：" plus one space.
The content wrapped by the custom environment is flexible, which means there may be an indefinite number of lines between "借：" and "贷：" (or zero). Similarly, the content after "贷：" is also indefinite

If we consider "借：" and "贷：" as the first and second identifiers respectively, then:
Lines between these two identifiers should be indented by \qquad
The second identifier should be indented by \quad
Lines after the second identifier should be indented by \quad \qquad

Please edit your query to post these pieces of information there, so that more people will see it. It's also easier to apply visual formatting to the code in the query than it is in a comment. Thanks.

I have synchronized the modifications to my question, thank you
